# how to combine sqlite3 tables from different .db files in node.js ( with same number of rows )

Tags: sql, node.js, datatables, electron, node-sqlite3

```
  masterTable.all(`SELECT ledger_num,file_num,client_name,vehicle_number,vehicle_model,registered_on FROM masterTable` , (err,data) => {
    w = getPureArray2d(data)
    reminderTable.all(`SELECT reminder_created_on ,upcoming_reminder_date , last_reminder_message ,status FROM reminderTable` , (err,data2) => {
      x = getPureArray2d(data2)
      updatesTable.all(`SELECT total_balance ,last_paid_date FROM updatesTable` , (err,data3) => {
        y = getPureArray2d(data3)
        masterTable.all(`SELECT phone_number1 ,phone_number2 ,phone_number3 agreementEx, permitEx  FROM masterTable` , (err,data4) => {
          z = getPureArray2d(data4)
          event.reply('gotAllDataForMasterTable', unionOnColumns(unionOnColumns(unionOnColumns(w,x),y),z))
        })
      })
    })
  })
```

I am trying to merge data from multiple data base into a single array , this is to create a table in my electron app and
, **the number of rows in all the data base are the same** so I am bringing them in and the merging them with a function

I am using a separate function to perform union

```
function unionOnColumns(first,second) {
  var mergeOnRows = second.map((item, i) => {
      return [...first[i], ...item];
  });
  return mergeOnRows
}
```

this seems like a really stupid way... so is there a better way of getting data from multiple database and merging them into a single array

Comment: why do you have 3 db files at all?

Comment: I am using this is in an electron app and sometimes i have to send a particular file to a different user so it was easier to just send the particular file than to have everything in a single db - and sometimes those files come from different users as well

Comment: you should read about databse and basic concepts, you have one databse, especially why you need to combine tables and you import new data and **not** copy file. it is sometimes simpler to copy files, but then you must live and join the tables in code and not in sql

Comment: yeah i did realize that but this was my first app and data base management - so now i am deep into the rabbit hole  and cant go back - and i also used an inappropriate date format dd/mm/yyyy instead of yyyy-mm-dd  and now my life is messed up

Comment: you simply need to rwrite  a little, instead of the copy of files write a function that import or modify 1 of the thousands they already existis, or live the the loops